# Can unwrap() method remove body element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a newbie in JQuery and I was wondering can unwrap() of the Jquery remove body element? I tried it but it doesn't work, i can't find the answer in google can any one explain me why this method doesn't removes body element when it called on some element inside the body ?

```
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
```

```js
$("p").unwrap();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. The `body` is an implicit part of the `document` structure and cannot be removed.

Comment: why don't you want to have a body in your document?

Comment: Perhaps if you explained *what you are trying to do* there may be a better solution?

Comment: to keep DOM valid, this method explicitely exclude BODY from parents matched set: `if ( !jQuery.nodeName( this, "body" ) )` If removing this check, HTML markup became invalid: http://jsfiddle.net/6agnkuvt/

Comment: This sounds like a bad solution to a problem. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment as answer:

The `body` is an implicit part of the `document` structure and cannot be removed. The same goes for the `tbody` element in a `table`. They exist in the DOM whether they are specified or not.

Also, as A. Wolff mentions in comment, the `unwrap()` method specifically excludes the `body` element in order to avoid it making invalid HTML.

Comment: nice one TrueBlueAussie! Great example.